# Why we need volumes inside services and volumes in docker compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to understand why we have `volumes` inside services in docker compose file and `volumes` outside services inside the same file please? Can't we just use one?

Below a durpal content management system is built with postgres database:

```
version: '2'

services:
  durpal:
    image: durpal
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - drupal-modules:/var/www/html/modules
      - drupal-profiles:/var/www/html/profiles
      - drupal-sites:/var/www/html/sites
      - drupal-themes:/var/www/html/themes
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD = mypasswd
volumes:
  - drupal-modules:
  - drupal-profiles:
  - drupal-sites:
  - drupal-themes:
```

Comment: One is the defenition of the volume (outside) and the other one is the usage (inside)

Comment: @GabeRAMturn. I am not sure what do you mean? Why we have defined it twice if we have device volumes for the service? Why we left volumes outside empty without path in the container as in `drupal-modules: , drupal-profiles: ...`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the official documentation:
With the [`volumes` top-level element](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-top-level-element) you *define* named volumes to be used in that `docker-compose.yml`.

With the [`volumes` service property](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) on the other hand you specify where to mount the volumes in that container, referencing the named volumes defined in the top-level element.

The reason you (can) leave the definitions of the volumes empty is that the default values assigned for the omitted details are in most case already what you want. So only specifying the names of the volumes is enough to get them created with the default configurations.
Look at the [`volumes` top-level element documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-top-level-element) to see what other configurations are available.

To learn more about volumes see [this page in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-with-docker-compose).